# Enforcing newlines separating code blocks in eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've been scouring the Eslint rule docs and cannot figure out how to enforce newlines between blocks.

For example, in jscs I can reject these for having no separating new line:

```
if (!rows.length) {
  // code
}
var pagination;
if (something) {
  // code
}
```

"space-before-blocks" sounded like it's what I wanted but it applies only to spaces, not newlines.

Comment: For the record, you can use [newline-after-var](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/newline-after-var) to enforce a break after the `var` declaration. I'm still anxious to find a rule to enforce separation of the two `if` blocks in the case where the `var` isn't there, though.

Answer (score 20):

Response is a bit late but you can now use the `padding-line-between-statements` rule for this: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements

I think the config you'd want would be something like

```
"padding-line-between-statements": [
  "warn",
  { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block' },
  { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'block', next: '*' },
  { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block-like' },
  { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'block-like', next: '*' },
]
```